# Passing Data Between Route and Nested Route in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

Using a React Hooks and React Router v6, how do you load and define data on parent `Events` load and then pass subset of events data to the dynamic nested route -- `campaign`. I am planning to define and set state of Campaigns within the `Events` Route.

Since I am defining the routing on the index.js file, I am trying to see how to best pass this data from the parent Route to the nested Route, since the data is not yet defined in the `index.js` view.

```
<Route path="events" element={<Events />}>
  <Route path=":event" element={<Event campaign={campaign} />} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't pass something via props, and it cannot be derived by the route params, you'd use context instead.

In your example, `<Event />` will be rendered where you place `<Outlet />`. You can wrap a context provider around your usage of `<Outlet />` within the `<Events />` component:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext();
const Events = () => {
  return <MyContext.Provider value={{greeting: "Hello, world!"}}>
    <Outlet />
  </MyContext.Provider>;
};
```

And then you can access this value within the event component by using that same context:

```
const Event = () => {
  const { greeting } = React.useContext(MyContext);
  return <span>{greeting}</span>;
};
```

In order to make code easier to follow, *where possible*, I would recommend propagating information in the following preference order:

1. Via props to the child component (either by passing the data itself, or some ID of the data which can be used to retrieve it from a data store)
2. Have the child component determine the information from the URL
3. Pass data from parent to child via context

This is also in order of explicitness - be more explicit where possible.

For your precise example, I would recommend using a combination of context and ids; each Campaign likely has its own ID, so I'd design an API that looked like this:

```
const Events = () => {
  const campaignStore = useCampaignStore();
  return <CampaignContext.Provider value={campaignStore}>
    <React.Suspense fallback={<span>Loading...</span>}>
      <Outlet />
    </React.Suspense>
  <CampaignContext.Provider>
}

const Event = ({ campaignID }) => {
  const campaign = useCampaign(campaignID);
  ....
}
```

Where `useCampaign` would be some hook that would throw to enable suspense if a value was not yet available.